# Generate random emoji with plain Java

Tags: java, emoji

is there any easy way to create random emojis using java?

Did only find libraries which use a file as their data source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s a full list of unicode-supported emoji [here](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html). As you scroll down this list, you’ll see why these libraries choose to rely on a data file instead of a set of generation rules.

Many emoji characters are represented by multiple code points, not all of which are even in the same code page, let alone the same length. To map a random number generator to the spectrum of emoji would be a very difficult (impossible?) task without a complete list of emoji.

Comment: thought about that too, hoped there was something i overlooked :/

Comment: If you want to generate a random emoji from a specific subset, the story may change. Just look for patterns in the code points that would allow a simple mapping to a random integer